# ASP.NET Core related field is required error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have two related classes, Organiser and Season, in my ASP.NET Core 5.0 Web API. They are defined by the models below and are mapped properly to a MySQL database using Entity Framework Core. I've removed some unrelated fields.

```
public class Organiser
{   
    #nullable enable
    public Guid OrganiserId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<Season> Seasons { get; set; } = new List<Season>();
}
```

Season has a foreign key relation to Organiser, defined with OrganiserId and Organiser

```
public class Season
{
    #nullable enable
    public Guid SeasonId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    [Required]
    public Guid OrganiserId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    [ForeignKey("OrganiserId")]
    public Organiser Organiser { get; set; }
}
```

My SeasonController looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult InsertSeason([FromBody] Season season)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid ||
            DateTime.Compare(season.RegistrationStart,season.RegistrationEnd) > 0 ||
            DateTime.Compare(season.RegistrationEnd, season.SeasonStart) > 0)

        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        _seasonService.InsertSeason(season);
        return Created("~api/Season/"+season.SeasonId.ToString(), season);
    }
```

I have issues with trying to insert a new Season object. The organiserId field in my Json corresponds to an existing Organiser object in the database, however I hit an error in the controller. I get a 400 error with a "The Organiser field is required". An Organiser field is missing from the Json body, yes, but it is both tagged with JsonIgnore and is "covered" by the OrganiserId field (which is included in the body). I've made ASP.NET Core Web API's before, but I've never had this problem.

Comment: A good reason to keep your entities and MVC models completely separate.

Comment: I suspect your attributes are reversed. Put `[Required]` and `[ForeignKey("Organiser")` on 
`public Guid OrganiserId { get; set; }`. and don't put any Attributes on `public Organiser Organiser { get; set; }`. And it always recommended to had different ViewModel and Entities separated for behaviors and additional data you want to be isolated, it's clean coding.

Comment: I use DTO's to limit the model exposure, but should I use ViewModels as well?
Moving the ForeignKey tag does not change anything. I added it while debugging this very issue, but it should not be necessary as long as I stick to the default EF Core naming conventions.

Comment: I removed the #nullable enable and now everything seems to be working swimmingly. That being said, I'm interested to learn how I should separate my entities and models. As I said, I'm already using DTOs, but I do not see how they are relevant in this case.